# Richfaces editable dataTable not setting updated values in Bean

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have tried a bunch of suggestions after googling but none has so far worked for me. I am trying to display a simple datatable with editable inputText values in each row. table is being populated from database via a usual List of objects. Here is my xhtml page and managed bean

Richfaces 4.2.1, JSF 2 mojarra bundled with JBoss 7.1, JDK 1.6

```
<rich:dataTable value="#{wlScoreBean.scoreList}" binding="#{wlScoreBean.scoreTable}" var="item" id="table" style="width:100%">
        <rich:column>
            <f:facet name="header">PARAM NAME</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.paramName}" />
        </rich:column>
        <rich:column>
            <f:facet name="header">1 Score</f:facet>
             <h:inputText value="#{item.name1}" />
        </rich:column>
        <rich:column>
            <f:facet name="header">2 Score</f:facet>
             <h:inputText value="#{item.name2}" />
        </rich:column>
      </rich:dataTable>

        <br/>
        <h:panelGrid columns="3" id="buttonRow">
            <a4j:commandButton value="Save" render="table" execute="@this" action="#{wlScoreBean.update()}">                    
            </a4j:commandButton>
        </h:panelGrid>



import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.component.html.HtmlDataTable;
import javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent;

import org.richfaces.component.UIDataTable;


@ManagedBean(name = "wlScoreBean")
@ViewScoped
public class WS implements Serializable
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    private HtmlDataTable scoreTable;
    private List<WorkloadScore> scoreList;
    
    public void watchScore(ValueChangeEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("old value="+e.getOldValue() + ", New Value="+e.getNewValue());
    }

    public List<WorkloadScore> getScoreList() {
        return scoreList;
    }

    public void setScoreList(List<WorkloadScore> scoreList) {
        this.scoreList = scoreList;
    }

    @EJB
    private WorkloadScoreManagerService wlScoreManager;

    public HtmlDataTable getScoreTable() {
        return scoreTable;
    }

    public void setScoreTable(HtmlDataTable scoreTable) {
        this.scoreTable = scoreTable;
    }

    public WorkloadScoreBean()
    {
        
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void getAllScores()
    {
        this.scoreList = wlScoreManager.getAllScores();
    }
    
    public void update()
    {
        
        for (WorkloadScore wls : getScoreList())
        {
            System.out.println(wls.getParamName()+"="+wls.getPortabilityScore()+","+wls.getVirtualizationScore());
        }
        
        //wlScoreManager.update(workloadScore);
    }
}
```

Here's all the things I tried. All of them result in only the OLD VALUES being printed to console in the update() method.

1. Changed from rich:dataTable to plain old JSF h:dataTable, same result
2. Bound the dataTable to a Managed Bean property, checked in update() method, old values are being printed here too. I just did a getVlaue() on the UIDataTable object and cast it to List.

   The List is supposed to have been updated with changed values from the form, but I do not see it happening. I did make sure to put the MBean in ViewScope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See answer here https://community.jboss.org/thread/200684?tstart=0

I changed execute=@form and it worked! no need for ValueChangeEvent or messing with dataTable binding. The List values are updated in place and the update method prints the correct value

Answer (score 0):

do you have a h:form outside the datatable? and did you try to replace inputtext with inplaceinput fields?

Comment: yes i do have an h:form outside the table. i do notice that when i add a valueChangelistener to the inputText field, the event fires and new values are set on the bean. strange....